# Access DefaultListModel from another class

Tags: java, swing, defaultlistmodel

I want to add new items to my list model, but I dont know how to access the listmodel from another class.

I created it like this in the class GUI:

```
DefaultListModel<String> listenModell = new DefaultListModel<String>();
```

How can I access the listmodel in my other class?

I want to add items like this:

```
listenModell.add(i, result);
```

Comment: Make the `ListModel` a field, and create a getter ?

Comment: Provide mutable methods in the class which contains the JList

Comment: *"..but I dont know how to access the listmodel from another class."*  (rolls eyes) What IDE is writing the code?

Comment: I will try your approach @EricLeibenguth

Answer (score -1):

declare and initialize  as a static variable or instance variable with public access modifier  then you can call by using class name if it is static , or by using instance if it is instance variable . there you can add  .

ex:

```
public class Sample{
public static DefaultListModel<String> listenModell = new DefaultListModel<String>();
.
.
.


}


public class Sample2{
void method(){
Sample.listenModell.add(i,result);

}

}
```

Comment: Exposing through a static variable ... really ?

Comment: if you dont want to do like that you can declare it as private and provide getter method  ........

Comment: _if you dont want to do like_ I cannot think of a single reason why I would expose it through a public static variable.